# Gtk mouse drag implementation

Tags: c, gtk

Please provide sample code for implementation of mouse drag.

In Gtk (in C) I am Trying to catch a signal for mouse drag functionality.
But unfortunately couldn't do so.
I tried motion-notify-event but it is for pointer motion but not for mouse drag.
Also i couldn't understand drag-begin, drag-end or drag-motion,
Probably they are used for drag and drop, i just need to implement drag functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could help:
http://live.gnome.org/GnomeLove/DragNDropTutorial